# In a cabal package why should I have almost identical `other-modules` fields

Tags: haskell, cabal

In my cabal I have a `library` and a few `executable` fields. I can sort of understand why cabal wants to know about all the various files in the `.cabal` manifest, even the ones that are not `exposed-modules`. My executables only use modules in the `exposed-modules` of my library. Why then does cabal complain about missing `other-modules`?

```
version:             0.0.0.1
name:                my-pkg
synopsis:            A package
description:         Please see README.md
homepage:            https://homepage.com
license:             BSD3
license-file:        LICENSE
author:              Me
maintainer:          example@example.com
copyright:           MIT
category:            
build-type:          Simple
cabal-version:       >=1.10

library
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  ghc-options:         -Wall -g -Wno-simplifiable-class-constraints -O2
  exposed-modules:     MyLib.Exposed.ImportedByExec
  other-modules:       MyLib.NotExposed.ExecShouldntCare

executable tool
  hs-source-dirs:      tools/Tool
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  ghc-options:         -Wall -g -Wsimplifiable-class-constraints
  main-is:             Main.hs
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
                     , my-pkg >= 0.1.0.1
  other-modules:     <why should anything be here to avoid a warning??>
```

EDIT: Maybe the question is equivalent to "why does my-pkg not show up in `stack exec -- ghc-pkg list` after I `stack build` or even `stack install`?"

Comment: You have `version: 0.0.0.1` and `build-depends: my-pkg >= 0.1.0.1`. Seems wrong. After fixing that and putting blank-ish files in place for the three modules described by this cabal file (just a module header and either `NoImplicitPrelude` or `main = return ()` as appropriate), I cannot reproduce your problem: I get no warning about `other-modules` when I run `cabal v2-build all`. So you need to include the full details of what's in those files, what command you run, and possibly also what versions of the tools you have installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing the full contents of `tools/Tools` directory, we can only speculate as to why you are getting that error, but my guess would be that there are other haskell files in that directory.

`other-modules` indicates files/modules that are used in your project but are not publicly exposed. They are private files/modules. Details from the cabal page: [cabal - quickstart - 3.1.3. Modules included in the package](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#modules-included-in-the-package).

There is also a tool called [hpack](https://github.com/sol/hpack) which automates the creation of a `cabal` file from an `hpack` `yaml` file and it can automatically populate the `other-modules` field for you. You can also use it via [stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/faq/#does-stack-support-the-hpack-specification).

Comment: Yes! this is perfect. I couldn't make a small example but I moved my .cabal to hpack and now everything works perfectly